# Laravel 5 link does not work properly

Tags: php, laravel, url-routing, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am new to Laravel 5 Framework and I have a link as

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/AutoQlik/public/pages/aracislemler/?page=2">2</a>
```

and its route is already defined as

```
Route::get('/pages/aracislemler', 'PagesController@aracislemler');
```

but when i click it, it goes to

> `http://localhost:8080/pages/aracislemler?page=2`

What might cause to this problem ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How is your route defined?

Comment: How you handle with controller ?

Comment: @silkfire i have edited the question please check it.

Comment: are you using nginx or apache?

Comment: @Digitlimit i am using Apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with your Laravel vhost setup in Apache. Your base url is `http://localhost:8080/AutoQlik/public/` . usually it should be `http://localhost:8080` instead .

Because of that somewhere your URL generation has not considered this and will go to different place.

If you check network tab if Firefox then you will see which url redirected you to wrong place and you can then fix the route handler handling this method if you do not want to reconfigure your Apache.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate links in your views like this:

```
href="{{ url('pages/aracislemler/?page=2') }}"
```

and it will put in the base url for you.

Not sure if that will fix your problem though, but that's how you do it.